Issue with understanding the frequency response of an open-loop flyback converter
I am trying to simulate the frequency response of a flyback converter circuit as shown below to verify the location of the poles and zeros.

Attached below is the frequency response obtained after running the simulation.

We can see that there is a peaking of the amplitude response due to resonance. However, I am not understanding the nature of the response. Shouldn't the response be flat at frequencies below resonance?
Could anybody explain the plot or what I am doing wrong?

When you perform an AC analysis in a simulator, devices such as voltage operated switches just do not work and, the simulator will use their open-circuit impedance instead. You really need to make what is called an "average" model of the circuit in order to perform AC analysis in a simulator.
Or, my old-fashioned (but personally preferred) method is to run a transient analysis with V4 acting as a square wave and, analyse the overshoot at the output.

As pointed out by Andy Aka, if you want the ac small-signal response of a switching converter, you can either resort to an average model or use a piece-wise linear (PWL) simulator like SIMPLIS. SIMPLIS can extract the ac response from a switching circuit, without the intermediate step of average modeling.
If you want to simulate the control-to-output transfer function of a switching converter, you need a modulator to generate the duty ratio. If you look at the below example in SIMPLIS, you can see a comparator receiving a ramp on its (+) pin while the (-) pin is biased by a dc voltage. When the ramp intersects the dc bias, toggling occurs and the transistor turns off. This is a pulse-width modulator (PWM). If you insert an ac source in series with this dc bias, you can sweep the ac response of the converter at low and high line:

I would recommend you take a look at my tutorial on SIMPLIS which will guide you on how to simulate a basic converter and extract its ac response. Then, if you truly want to understand how to derive the poles and zeroes of this converter, have a look at my book dedicated to transfer functions but that is a heavy read ^_^
